# mvc5 secure aspx form pages based on user identity or role identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

- MVC5 Application
- Report Viewer + Rdlc + aspx included in cshtml(ifram) for view by controller
- aspx forms are in folder name ReportFolder
- even not login i can access, http://project/ReportFolder/report.aspx for security did this:

  ```
   <location path="ReportFolder"  >
      <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <deny users="*"/>
          <allow roles="Admin"/>            
        </authorization>
      </system.web>
    </location>
  ```

  - now i am not able to access even user is admin and authenticated

Comment: i do not know why i got down vote,please let us know reason when u vote, so many reason less people in the world while they pass by form ur side u know what they do lol...

Answer (score 0):

Usually `allow` nodes should always come before `deny`. Try this:

```
<location path="ReportFolder"  >
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="Admin"/>
        <allow roles="Admin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>           
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```